# Timeout on remote database connection at Heroku

Tags: mysql, database, heroku

Its possible connect to a remote mysql database on a heroku application?

I'm trying to connect on a [umbler](http://app.umbler.com) remote database and getting a timeout error:

`"at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/public/estabelecimentos/11" host=cheff-casa.herokuapp.com request_id=41221e2c-0dc5-4ffc-8915-2018a4cee9b3 fwd="191.240.220.62" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http"`

My connection string: "jdbc:mysql://" + DB_HOST + ":" + DB_PORT + "/jfood?**sslmode=require**"

Obs.:

- Already tried with and without sslmode=require;
- Remote database access is active;
- Connection it's ok on localhost;
- If I change to clearDB, it works fine (clearDB allow only 5mb);
- Already tried add connectTimeout=120000 on connection string;
- [This doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely) its about connect Heroku Postgres remotely. I cant do it to mysql? '-'

Answer (score 2):

I solve it, umbler database hasn't SSL mode active. Heroku require SSL mode to connect to a remote databse.

Comment: To know if your databse has SSL you can run: mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';

Comment: app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect